# Looking for title about a ship that seeds planets and then monitors them

Tags: story-identification, books, spaceship, space-colonization

I'm looking for the title of a book about a ship that has colonized several systems, and is now traveling from planet to planet, monitoring their progress.

The ship is AI/sentient. And much of the narrative is the from the ship.

One planet has the people turning into trees. Another has people who think they should only sleep 3 hours a day.

I know that's kind of vague but it was about 20 years ago when I read this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This reminded me immediately of a book my son told me about, John Brunner's "[A Maze of Stars](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1544)".  I haven't read it myself but online [reviews](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/872229.A_Maze_of_Stars) do sound like it might be it:

> A slow but interesting book about a colonization ship seeding humanity
> throughout the galaxy..or rather revisiting these planets at a point
> 500 years from the start of the work. Mostly a tale of what went wrong
> with each attempt..has all the big ones...genetic mutation,
> dictatorships, backwards societies and immortality ( at the cost of
> mindlessness through symbiosis ), etc... I think it would have
> been/could have been better if it actually explained some of the
> questions posed in the novel rather than explaining things by saying
> that there is/might be a gap in the ships knowledge banks..or that its
> programming would not allow explanations for 'that topic'.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I've been trying to track this down for a few years!

Comment: You are most welcome! Maybe I should read it....

Answer (score 3):

I've searched online and from research I can't be sure, but I found

[World's Best Science Fiction: 1971](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World's_Best_Science_Fiction:_1971)

Technically, it's an anthology series, but of note is "Gone are the Lupo", in which the people of a newly colonised planet are turning into trees. I don't believe that particular story mentions a seed ship or people with little sleep, but something like that may be in one of the other stories.

Comment: Hmm... not that one, but thank you.